# SSI timefmt suppress leading zero in the hour

Tags: ssi

This [Server Side Include](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) fragment:

```
<!--#config timefmt="%a, %d%b'%y %I:%M%P %Z" -->
Content updated: <!--#flastmod virtual='../pages/$JLC_CONTENT_FILE' -->
```

produces:

[image: Page result with leading zero on the hour.]

How can one suppress the leading zero in the hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timefmt` uses the standard C function [strftime()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html), so "%k" drops the leading zero:

```
<!--#config timefmt="%a, %e%b'%y %k:%M%P %Z" -->
```